# Oyster Caps - Zone 1-2 Cappted travel with Single Ticket ontop

Tags: tickets, tfl, oyster-card

Can someone please explain this?

I did one journey from Zone 8, and the rest of my time was spent in Zones 1-2. I have a 16-25 Railcard on my Oyster so the Zone 1-2 cap is £4.35 and the zones 1-8 is £8.

So my question is - assuming that Oyster works out the cheapest journey at all points why wasn't I capped? Yes - I didn't meet the zone 1-8 cap, but I definitely did for the zones 1-2 cap with my travel round there. Therefore shouldn't Oyster cap my Zones 1-2 travel separately and then have the zone 8 single fare on top. It seems in my case I have not been charged the cheapest fare.

See pic: [image: Oyster]

Tried contacting customer services, they said they 'thought' zones 1-2 would cap if I traveled around there first and then made my zone 8 single travel, but not the other way round which I did.

Answer (score 1):

Oyster capping is a complicated beast, but I think I have an answer for you.

There are two caps - *Anytime* and *Off Peak*

*Anytime* for your card is set at £6.60 for Zones 1-2

*Off Peak* for your card is set at £4.35 for Zones 1-2

Journeys are tallied against the running totals of all applicable caps, so all journeys are tallied against the *Anytime* cap but only some are tallied against the *Off Peak* cap.

Your Zone 1-2 travel is split across both of those caps, with all three journeys being tallied against the *Anytime* cap running total but only two journeys being tallied against the *Off Peak* cap running total.

Your cap totals are thusly £4.80 for *Anytime* and £3.20 for *Off Peak* in Zones 1-2, so neither cap was reached.

Comment: I follow what you say but it doesn't quite match up for me:
[url=https://ibb.co/kqH7XF][img]https://preview.ibb.co/mWbeev/Oyster_Reply_1.png[/img][/url]
This shows me reaching an off peak cap during the peak on a different day, so surely then it's not the timing but actually the zones.

This also makes sense with what london oyster says: [Here](http://www.oyster-rail.org.uk/peak-off-peak-and-caps/) which says that the caps in the evening peak that are applied are off peak caps, even if a full price peak single fare is charged. 

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: I screwed up the picture sorry it is
[Here](https://preview.ibb.co/mWbeev/Oyster_Reply_1.png)

Comment: @TomGill that page on oyster-rail.org.uk is wrong, it's a third party site, so don't assume it's correct.